# How to parallel process elements in an list to sum them all using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Given that the addition has the conmutative property, no need to sum the objects in a serializable mode, we could for example sum the elements by couples and then sum the results, or sum the first part of the list, then the second, and sum both results, to make it more effective.
I'm trying to do that with parallel processing in Java but I'm not very familiar with the API yet.

Is this possible using parallel Streams?

THis is the snippet of code I started to write but I don't know how to continue.. Thanks

```
        Long result=CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(accounts)?accounts.stream().parallel().mapToLong(account->account.getBalance))
```

Comment: The way that could be done in Scala is with foldLeft which has a built-in accumulator.  For strings that could be done with org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join. For numbers, a starting point could be coding a function similar to either in Java.  Maybe the code for join could be modified to do it.

Comment: @Tris come on now: what is the point of answering a question with "in language X this can be done" where X is not the language that is asked for?

Comment: Because is gives clues for a starting point. Which reminds me that Functional Java may well have foldLeft since it was written by the same person as scalaz.

Comment: Sure enough Functional Java Stream has 4 foldLeft functions, see https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/fj/data/Stream.html.  Admittedly it is not precisely Java 8, but it could run using Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
accounts.stream().mapToLong(Account::getBalance).parallel().sum();
```

which is the same as

```
accounts.stream().mapToLong(Account::getBalance).parallel().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b);
```

Please note: doing this operation in parallel only really starts saving time when working with extremely large sets of numbers. On smaller sets it is actually slower, because of the parallelization overhead. This code runs about twice the speed because of the parallel operator:

```
    int intCount = 100_000_000;
    int x[] = new int[intCount];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++) {
        x[i] = rand.nextInt();
    }

    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) {
        Arrays.stream(x).parallel().sum();
    }

    System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ts));
```

Lowering intCount to 1 I can see I am paying about 5ms (over 100 iterations) overhead for parallelization on my machine, which is quite a lot of time for doing practically nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you ask is map/reduce algorithm. As far as I know, there's no generic map/reduce in JDK8, but particular implementations use it. Look for example this will be implemented in parallel/sequential modes:

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] { 1, 2}).sum();
```

The reading of the Parallel API source is really good for education.